# how to read and display tsv file with using colletion

Tags: java

I added data of tsv file to list. but it repeatedly giving data.

this is tsv file

```
UserID  City    State   Country ZipCode DegreeType  Major   GraduationDate  WorkHistoryCount           TotalYearsExperience CurrentlyEmployed   ManagedOthers   ManagedHowMany
47  Paramount   CA  US  90723   High School     6/1/1999 0:00   3   10  Yes No  0
72  La Mesa CA  US  91941   Master's    Anthropology    1/1/2011 0:00   10  8   Yes No  0
80  Williamstown    NJ  US  8094    High School Not Applicable  6/1/1985 0:00   5   11  Yes Yes 5
98  Astoria NY  US  11105   Master's    Journalism  5/1/2007 0:00   3   3   Yes No  0
```

this is my code

```
public class tsv_read{

public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {

BufferedReader TSVFile = 
    new BufferedReader(new FileReader("tsvfile.tsv"));

String dataRow = TSVFile.readLine();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (dataRow != null){
String[] dataArray = dataRow.split("\t");
for (String item:dataArray) { 

   list.add(item);

    } 
Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   String txt = it.next();
   System.out.print(txt);
} 
System.out.println(); // Print the data line.
dataRow = TSVFile.readLine(); 
}

TSVFile.close();

System.out.println();

} //main()
}
```

this is the output that i have got

```
    UserIDCityStateCountryZipCodeDegreeTypeMajorGraduationDateWorkHistoryCountTotalYearsExperienceCurrentlyEmployedManagedOthersManagedHowMany
     UserIDCityStateCountryZipCodeDegreeTypeMajorGraduationDateWorkHistoryCountTotalYearsExperienceCurrentlyEmployedManagedOthersManagedHowMany47ParamountCAUS90723High School6/1/1999 0:00310YesNo0
  UserIDCityStateCountryZipCodeDegreeTypeMajorGraduationDateWorkHistoryCountTotalYearsExperienceCurrentlyEmployedManagedOthersManagedHowMany47ParamountCAUS90723High School6/1/1999 0:00310YesNo072La MesaCAUS91941Master'sAnthropology1/1/2011 0:00108YesNo0
  UserIDCityStateCountryZipCodeDegreeTypeMajorGraduationDateWorkHistoryCountTotalYearsExperienceCurrentlyEmployedManagedOthersManagedHowMany47ParamountCAUS90723High School6/1/1999 0:00310YesNo072La MesaCAUS91941Master'sAnthropology1/1/2011 0:00108YesNo080WilliamstownNJUS8094High SchoolNot Applicable6/1/1985 0:00511YesYes5
  UserIDCityStateCountryZipCodeDegreeTypeMajorGraduationDateWorkHistoryCountTotalYearsExperienceCurrentlyEmployedManagedOthersManagedHowMany47ParamountCAUS90723High School6/1/1999 0:00310YesNo072La MesaCAUS91941Master'sAnthropology1/1/2011 0:00108YesNo080WilliamstownNJUS8094High SchoolNot Applicable6/1/1985 0:00511YesYes598AstoriaNYUS11105Master'sJournalism5/1/2007 0:0033YesNo0
```

I want output like table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add

```
list.clear();
```

at the beginning of each run through the loop.

```
while (dataRow != null){
    list.clear();
    String[] dataArray = dataRow.split("\t");
    // etc.
```

What's happening at the moment is that your `List` is growing and growing... in the first line, you add all the fields from that line, and then in the second line you add all those fields onto the end, and so on... but you never empty the list and start again.

The alternative solution would be to move the `List` declaration inside the loop:

```
String dataRow = TSVFile.readLine();
while (dataRow != null){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] dataArray = dataRow.split("\t");
    // etc.
```

That way, you end up with a new list each time.

If you're wondering why the fields you're printing are all run together, by the way, it's because you're repeatedly calling `System.out.print(txt)` without any kind of separator. You might want to start with `System.out.print(txt+" ")`, until you decide the exact formatting you'd like.

Comment: @MadhaviTalla You're welcome! Please do click the tick to mark as accepted answer if you found it helpful. (Gives you some rep points too.)

Comment: can i search data from list? it means I want to use list as database

Comment: @MadhaviTalla You should probably submit that as a separate question. There is `list.contains()` but it's not a very efficient solution. If you want to use your data as a database, you should think about using a database...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class tsv_read1{

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader TSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("tsvfile.tsv"));
        List<String>dataArray = new ArrayList<String>() ;
        String dataRow = TSVFile.readLine();
        while (dataRow != null){
            dataArray.add(dataRow);
            dataRow = TSVFile.readLine();
        }
        TSVFile.close();    
        for(String item:dataArray){
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }       
}
```